Convert CSV tables to MediaWiki tables
Input a CSV table, like this:
data00,data01,data02,...,data0m
data10,data11,data12,...,data1m
...
datan0,datan1,datan2,...,datanm

The cells in the CSV table is guaranteed to contain only letters or numbers, and there’s no extra whitespace.
Your task is to convert it to a MediaWiki table, and output it, like this:
{|
| data00 || data01 || data02 || ... || data0m
|-
| data10 || data11 || data12 || ... || data1m
|-
...
|-
| datan0 || datan1 || datan2 || ... || datanm
|}

Your output must strictly follow this format, except for the whitespaces before or after each cell.
For example, input:
a,b,c
1,2,3

Will output:
{|
| a || b || c
|-
| 1 || 2 || 3
|}

but
{|
| a || b || c
|-
|1||2||3
|}

is also a valid output.
This is code-golf, so use the fewest bytes.

Rust, 73 bytes 68 bytes

Reduced to 68 bytes thanks to corvus_192

|s|format!("{{|
|")+&s.replace(",","||").replace("
","
|-
|")+"
|}";

Try it online!

65 bytes: |s|format!("{{| ")+&s.replace(",","||").replace(" "," |- ")+" |}"

(stack exchange ate the newlines, sorry about that)

This is missing the | at the start of each line of cells.

@corvus_192 That gives me an error saying that type annotations are needed for "s". Once I set it up and fix the missing | (as pointed out by @bigyihsuan), it's 73 bytes... maybe I'm missing something?  Here's the link: Try it online!

Just put a type sugnature after let f: TIO

Retina, 25 bytes
,
||
¶
¶|-¶|
^
{|¶|
$
¶|}

Attempt This Online!

Perl 5 -p0, 35 bytes
s/
/
|-
|/g;s/,/||/g;$_="{|
|$_
|}"

Try it online!

Go, 102 bytes
import."strings"
func f(s string)string{R:=ReplaceAll
return`{|
|`+R(R(s,",","||"),`
`,`
|-
|`)+`
|}`}

Attempt This Online!

sed, 31 bytes
1i{|
1!i|-
s/^/|/
s/,/||/g
$a|}

Try it online!

Charcoal, 20 bytes
{|¶ＷＳ⁺|⟦⪫⪪ι,×|²-⟧Ｍ↗}

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings. Explanation:
{|¶

Output the table start.
ＷＳ

Loop over each row.
⁺|⟦⪫⪪ι,×|²-⟧

Replace the commas in the row with ||, then print both the row and a -, but prefixing a | to each. (×|² is shorter than || because it doesn't need to be separated from the adjacent strings.)
Ｍ↗}

Change the last table row into a table end.
17 bytes to print using the alternative cell format:
{|¶ＷＳ⁺|⊞Ｏ⪪ι,¦-Ｍ↗}

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings. Explanation: As above except each row is split on commas and a - is appended to the list before each element is prefixed with |.

JavaScript (ES6), 51 bytes
s=>`{|
|${s.replace(/\W/g,c=>1/c?`
|-
|`:`||`)}
|}`

Try it online!
Commented
with funny colors, courtesy of highlight.js
s =>              // s = input string
`{|\n|${          // append the leading string "{|\n|"
  s.replace(      // replace in s:
    /\W/g,        //   because the data fields are guaranteed
                  //   to contain only letters and digits, it
                  //   is safe to use \W to match all commas
                  //   and newline characters at once
    c =>          //   given the matched character c ...
      1 / c ?     //     if c = "\n" (which is zero'ish):
        `\n|-\n|` //       append the row separator
      :           //     else:
        `||`      //       append the column separator
  )               //   end of replace()
}\n|}`            // append the trailing string "\n|}"


Vyxal, 149 bitsv2, 18.625 bytes
⌐ƛ\|dj\-M;fṪ¤ø.\|vp⁋øḃ

Try it Online!
Bitstring:
00011000001001100101010010010000100010000101001011101000010010010110110010001010110101010011111010101100011110000111011001000010001001111011110011110

-1.5 bytes from doing the dash separator inside the map function
⌐ƛ\|dj;:L‹\-ẋY¤ø.\|vp⁋øḃ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
⌐                         # ‎⁡split strings on commas
 ƛ    ;                   # ‎⁢for each row
     j                    # ‎⁣join on the string
  \|d                     # ‎⁤"||"
            ẋ             # ‎⁢⁡repeat the string...
          \-              # ‎⁢⁢"-"
       :L‹                # ‎⁢⁣rows-1 times 
             Y            # ‎⁢⁤interleave with separated list
              ¤ø.         # ‎⁣⁡surround with empty string
                 \|vp     # ‎⁣⁢prepend a \| to each row
                     ⁋øḃ  # ‎⁣⁣join list on newlines and add curly braces to ends


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Python 3, 65 bytes 59 bytes

Removed 6 bytes thanks to corvus_192
Fixed an error as pointed out by bigyihsuan on my other answer where I forgot the | in front of each line of data

lambda s:"{|\n|"+s.translate({44:"||",10:"\n|-\n|"})+"\n|}"

Try it online!

57 bytes: lambda s:"{|\n"+s.translate({44:"||",10:"\n|-\n"})+"\n|}"

Google Sheets, 89 84 bytes
-5 bytes thanks to @doubleunary
="{|
"&REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","||"),"
","
-
"),"(?m)^","|")&"
|}"



You can save a byte by using hardcoded newlines instead of an array: ="{|↲"&regexreplace(regexreplace(substitute(A1,",","||"),"↲","$0-$0"),"(?m)^","|")&"↲|}". That also gets all of the result in one cell. Press Control+Enter to get newlines in place of ↲.

@doubleunary, nice! this helped me save 5 bytes by also using ↲ in place of $0 which saved 2 bytes and allowed me to SUBSTITUTE instead of REGEXREPLACE saving 2 more bytes.

JavaScript (Node.js), 58 bytes
s=>`{|
|${s.replace(/,/g,'||').replace(/\n/g,`
|-
|`)}
|}`

Attempt This Online!

05AB1E, 22 (or 20†) bytes
|',„||:'-.ý'}ª'|ì„{|š»

Input-lines as separated inputs.
Try it online.
†: If we're allowed to use a list of lines as I/O, it could be -2 bytes by removing the leading | and trailing »:
Try it online.
Explanation:
|                       # Get all inputs as a list of strings
 ',„||:                '# Replace all "," with "||" in each string
       '-.ý            '# Intersperse it with "-" delimiter
           '}ª         '# Append "}" to the list
              '|ì      '# Prepend "|" in front of each inner string
                 „{|š   # Prepend "{|" to the list
                     »  # Join the list with newline delimiter
                        # (after which the result is output implicitly)


AWK, 75 bytes
BEGIN{x="{|\n"}{gsub(/,/,"||");x=x (1~NR?"|":"-\n|")$0"\n|"}END{print x"}"}

Try it online!
AWK is pretty clear about concatenating strings, so we're just jamming in the extra formatting. Run it thus, with the csv file of choice:
awk 'BEGIN{x="{|\n"}{gsub(/,/,"||");x=x (1~NR?"|":"-\n|")$0"\n|"}END{print x"}"}' data.csv


66 bytes, using -F, -vOFS=||: BEGIN{printf"{|\n|"}NR~2{s="|-\n|"}{$1=$1;print s$0}END{print"|}"} https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzryRNqbomJq9GqdYvqM6outhWqUYXzK1WMbRVMbQGq1EoVjGodfVzgehQqqlVqv3/PyWxJNHAQAdMGUIoIx09PT0IM5cLRBlC5A0h8oYIeUOIvBEB/UaGOPX/yy8oyczPK/6v66bzX7fM3y3YtqYGAA

APL+WIN, 61 bytes.
Prompts for CSV as a nested matrix of rows:
m←⎕⋄((∊,m=',')/∊,m)←⊂'||'⋄⊃(⊂'{|'),(¯1↓,('|',¨m),⊂'|-'),⊂'|}'

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic
